# How do I modify this makefile so that it compiles .java files located in src directory?

Tags: java, jar, javac

And also so that it puts the .class files in a ClassDir directory? So far, I've only been able to make it work when everything is in same directory.

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

# This uses the line continuation character (\) for readability
CLASSES = \
        Context.java \
        ClosedState.java \
        OpenState.java \
        Floor.java \
        State.java \
        Elevator.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
        $(RM) *.class
```

Comment: Searching for "java makefile" will help. But... why.

Comment: Is it commonplace to put the makefile in the src directory?

Comment: @marti Using make is uncommon in Java. Use Maven, use gradle, use sbt. Also, `$(JC) $(JFLAGS) src/$*.java` and `JFLAGS = -g -d bin` might do it. I'm not certain. I don't use make with Java.

Comment: It's uncommon to use make at all in Java projects. But no, the makefile would be at the root level. It's doable--just not a great idea in the long run.